# opening smb://user@server/share URLs no longer works

Tags: mojave, smb

Recently, I noticed that when I try to open `smb://` URLs that contain a share (exact syntax: `smb://user@server.domain/share`), I am just presented the dialog asking which shares I want to mount, but in the past it would directly mount the given share and open a Finder window.  (I am typically using `open smb://...` from the commandline, but I think the same holds for links on intranet pages from within Safari.)

Is this a limitation of Mojave (my suspicion is that this is caused by the upgrade, but I am not sure)? Do other people have the same problem? Is there a setting or workaround for this?

Update: It started working again, maybe through one of the updates Mojave got in the meantime. This status update is written on macOS 10.14.3, which allows to directly open shares again. (I only get a password prompt, but not the annoying share choice when specifying the share already.)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, it seems to be that you have to go to finder and "Command + K" to get a share to mount properly. It's driving me nuts as I have a stickie with all my server links and this new dialog shows...!

Comment: For me it started working again, I believe through one of the updates Mojave got in the meantime.  (I am even still on 10.14.3, while 10.14.4 is already waiting to be installed.)